# keypress and keydown providing different codes via event.which

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using firefox and when I use event.which to figure out what key caused an event to fire, I get different codes when checking event.which from a keypress event vs. a keydown event.

When using the '-' key (hyphen/minus).  I get a value of 45 for event.which when reporting based off a keypress event, but a value of 173 when reporting based off of a keydown event.

For keypress, I get the wrong code if the expected code is a value greater than 128 (I get expected_code & 0x7f).  But, if I do the same using a keydown, I get the expected code.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fzd3fjqm/1/

```
html:

<input id="whichkey" value="type something">
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="log2"></div>

javascript:

$( "#whichkey" ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
$( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " + event.which );
});
$( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
$( "#log2" ).html( event.type + ": " + event.which )
});
```

Is this expected?

I was writing a function triggered from keypress and filtering keys based on event.which and it doesn't work well with the described behavior.

If this is expected, what is the correct way to determine what key was press from withing a function triggered by keypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the `keyCode` is different for each event (and varies among browsers): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: I am not complaining about the result of keyCode and charCode being different.  I am complaining about the keyCode being different when I check event.which for a keypress event vs a keydown event.

Comment: @corbin Check out the link, it says why.

Comment: For keypress, it then seems that neither which, keyCode or charCode can be used effectively then.  As which and charCode return 45 for the example given and keyCode returns 0.  The real answer is 173.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to deterime the key pressed that is triggering keypress?